# Returning the numbers in a list whose sum is a given target

Tags: python, performance, list

```
input = x[1,2,4,6,3,9]
target = 6
```

o/p:
the first number is 1 and the second number is 5

I came across this problem and I solved it using this code:

```
def search(a,b):
    for d in b:
        if a==d:
            m=True
            break
        else:
            m=False
    return m

x=[1,4,5,7,9,6,2]
target=int(raw_input("Enter the number:"))
for i in x:
    if i<target:
        pair=int(target)-int(i)
        in2=search(pair,x)
        if in2==True:
            print "the first number= %d the second number %d"%(i,pair)
            break
```

How can I do this better or in a more efficient manner?

Comment: Since this is working and you just want feedback and suggestions you could think about putting this on the Code Review site. Take a look at the site's [how to ask](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: This question should be asked on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Please, explain the problem your code is solving in plain English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is as follows:

```
x = [1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 6, 2]
target = int(raw_input("Enter the number:"))
for i in xrange(len(x)):
    for ii in xrange(len(x)):
        if (x[i] + x[ii]) == target:
            print "the first number= %d the second number %d" % (x[i], x[ii])
```

Basically I iterate through the loop twice searching for a case in which the first index + some other index is equal to your target number, then the second index and so on so forth. I hope I was of help. You can add a `quit()` after the print to quit after the first found match. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for adding this.
one question, how can we make this generic like if combination of two number doesn't match the  target then program should check for other combination like combination of 3 numbers up-to n number of combination

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of pairs for the numbers that sum the desired target:

```
>>> [(x,y) for x in [1,2,3] for y in [1,2,3] if x+y == 3]
[(1, 2), (2, 1)]
```

The generic one would be:

```
>>> [(x,y) for x in lst for y in lst if x+y == target]
```

In case you just need the numbers whithout the pairs

```
>>> set([x for x in lst for y in lst if x+y == target])
```

This is not the most efficient way maybe, but is a pythonic way and will work.

Answer (score 0):

Same as Damian's answer but with itertools

```
import itertools
x=[1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 6, 2]
target=6
for l in itertools.combinations(x,2):
    if l[0]+l[1]==target:
         print("the first number= %d the second number %d" % l)
```

If the elements in `x` are strictly positive, you should remove all elements greater or equal to the target before creating the combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Credit for idea: https://youtu.be/kVgy1GSDHG8 - "If you are stuck, throw a has map at it".

We can solve this in linear time using dictionaries. In the dictionary, use the number value as key, and its index as the value. That way, when iterating through, we can efficiently check if difference (target - current_number) is a number we have already iterated through.

```py
x = [1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 6, 2]
target = 6


def getIndices(lst, target):
    """Return indices i,j such that lst[i] + lst[j] = target.

    Assumes solution exists"""
    indexDict = {}
    for i, num in enumerate(x):
        difference = target - num
        try:
            j = indexDict[difference]
            return i, j
        except KeyError:
            indexDict[num] = i

print(getIndices(x, target))
```